# IBM MQ Connection using User Credentials Not Configuration Login from Service

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

Problem Statement:

When connecting to IBM MQ, credentials are taken from the user running the application, and not the MQ configuration properties set in the application trying to connect.

ERROR: Unauthorized

EX:

```
        var htProperties = new Hashtable();
        htProperties[MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY] = "IPADDRESS";
        htProperties[MQC.PORT_PROPERTY] = PORT;
        htProperties[MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY] = "CHANNEL";
        htProperties[MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY] = "user_id";
        htProperties[MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY] = "password";
```

I expect the Queue Manager to validate the credentials passed in to the Hashtable on the target system, but it takes the current login from my source computer and checks if their is a local account on the target system.

How can I override the local authentication and only use the authentication my services provide? What would I have to set up in terms of credentials on the target system?

I found this in the documentation..

```
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(USE.PW)
DEFINE AUTHINFO(USE.PW) +
AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) +
FAILDLAY(10) +
CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) +
CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

However, I don't know what the value of `USE.PW` is, and when going to execute it all at once, there are multiple syntax errors. Also, do I turn `CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL)`? What is the correct logic..

Answer (score 3):

In order to have the queue manager validate the credentials you provide, you must configure it to do so. You have already found the comment you need. To explain the command, as that seems to be your question:

You must create an AUTHINFO object containing the configuration your need, or alter an existing one. **Either** of these MQSC commands would be fine. The string `USE.PW` is simply the name of the object in the first example.

```
DEFINE AUTHINFO(USE.PW) +
       AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) +
       FAILDLAY(10) +
       CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) +
       CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED) +
       ADOPTCTX(YES)


ALTER AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS) +
      AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) +
      CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) +
      CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED) +
      ADOPTCTX(YES)
```

You must then ensure the queue manager is using the configuration in this object by providing the name of the object you used, into the `CONNAUTH` field on the queue manager. The name would either be `USE.PW` or `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS` depending on which of the above commands you used.

```
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(name-of-object)
```

Then finally, you must tell the queue manager that the configuration has been changed with the following command:

```
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

With regard to the values to use in the `CHCKLOCL` and `CHCKCLNT` fields. They have the same selection of values, but `CHCKLOCL` applies to connections that are made using local bindings connection (IPC), and `CHCKCLNT` applies to connections that are made using a client connection (network). If you have `OPTIONAL`, then if a password is provided it will be checked, but passwords are not mandated. It you have `REQUIRED` then if you do not provide a password to be checked the queue manager will not let you in.

Comment: Which part of that statement overrides the windows credential check?

Comment: If you have the `QMGR CONNAUTH` set to a valid `AUTHINFO` value, then any value of `CHKCLNT` will validate a password if present.  The value of `OPTIONAL` means that if a password is NOT present MQ will not attempt to validate it.  The value of `REQADM` means that if the user is a "admin" user it is required but for all other users it is the same as `OPTIONAL`.  The value `REQUIRED` as Morag stated means you can not get access with a empty password.

Comment: Unless you had a blank `QMGR CONNAUTH` then the password you sent would be checked regardless of the value unless you are on a older unsupported version of IBM MQ.  The .NET libraries were enhanced at MQ v8.0 to take the `MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY` and `MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY` passed in to .NET and send a `MQCSP` structure to the IBM MQ queue manager.  The `MQCSP` structure is what is authenticated by IBM MQ.  If you are using MQ v7.5 or lower this does not happen.  I suspect you are not at a supported level of IBM MQ.

Comment: @user2205904 - the use of CHCKCLNT/LOCL with value of something other than NONE causes the password to be checked, and the use of ADOPTCTX(YES) applies your supplied user instead of the windows user to be used for authority checking at the queue manager.